# Using Switch Case on Eval() value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a value retrieved using <%# Eval("Status") %> and I would like to switch this case inline in an ascx control without using a class or code behind. The switch case is fails requesting Enum, Interface or Struc.

```
<span class="label <%# GetStatus(Eval("Status").ToString()) %>">
  <%# Eval("Request_RequestStatus") %>
</span>
<%# 
protected String GetStatus(string stat) {

  var status = String.Empty;
   switch (stat)
   {
       case "New":
           status = "label-new";
           break;
       case "Approved":
           status = "label-approved";
           break;
       case "InProgress":
           status = "label-important";
           break;
       case "Overdue":
           status = "label-warning";
           break;
       case "Pending":
           status = "label-info";
           break;
       case "Completed":
           status = String.Empty;
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }   
    return status;
 }        
%>
```

The error error CS1513: } expected

Comment: Show us the code that you tried that failed.

Comment: What's the error you get? Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside `GetStatus()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetStatus()` function should be wrapped with

```
<script runat=server>
  protected String GetStatus(){...}
</script>
```

More details about code blocks can be found in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

And it could be better to use something like `(Container.DataItem as YourEntity).Status` instead of `Eval`